# What causes 403 rateLimitExceeded?

Tags: google-analytics-api

Which limit exactly are we exceeding when GA Core reporting API returns 403 rateLimitExceeded? That error code is not mentioned in the docs (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors#standard_errors). We're receiving both rateLimitExceeded and userRateLimitExceeded, so they seem to be different.

Answer (score 0):

`403 userRateLimitExceeded` is basically flood protection.   Your application can make a max of 10 requests a second for your user.  User is defined as IP address unless you send [QuotaUser](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/parameters) along with your request.

The per-user limit from the Developer Console has been reached.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "userRateLimitExceeded",
    "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "User Rate Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
```

403 rateLimitExceeded is the same thing just with a different name.  Why there are two cant tell you.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded",
    "reason": "rateLimitExceeded",
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Rate Limit Exceeded"
 }
}
```

In both cases you should [Implement Exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreErrors#backoff) and try the request again Just slower.

Comment: Thanks. But I think there must be some difference between these two, and that affects how we should handle them. We do send quotaUser and use exponential backoff. Could rateLimitExceeded be for the app as a whole, meaning a rate limit across all users?

Comment: As far as I know for the core reporting API there isn't any flood protection that is project based as opposed to user based.   But I could send an email off to the developers for clarification.   Will let you know when I hear back.   Sent: They are West Cost USA time so will be a while before I hear anything.

Comment: There is a difference between the two errors. `userRateLImitExceeded` is the per user rate limit `rateLimitExceeded` is a per project rate limit. Both can be found in the [Error Response table](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/errors#standard_errors), and both recommend Exponential backoff as DalmTo suggested.