# How to properly iterate Bigquery TableResult in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to iterate the rows from TableResult using `getValues()` as below.
if I use `getValues()`, it's retrieving only the first page rows. I want to iterate all the rows using `getValues()` and NOT using `iterateAll()`.
In the below code, the problem is its going infinite time. not ending. `while(results.hasNextPage())` is not ending. what is the problem in the below code?

```
    {
    query = "select from aa.bb.cc";
    QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig =
            QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query)
                    .setPriority(QueryJobConfiguration.Priority.BATCH)
                    .build();
    TableResult results = bigquery.query(queryConfig);

    int i = 0;
    int j=0;
    while(results.hasNextPage()) {
        j++;
        System.out.println("page " + j);
        System.out.println("Data Extracted::" + i + " records");
        for (FieldValueList row : results.getNextPage().getValues()) {
            i++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total Count::" + results.getTotalRows());
    System.out.println("Data Extracted::" + i + " records");
}
```

I have only 200,000 records in the source table. below is the out put and I forcefully stopped the process.

```
page 1
Data Extracted::0 records
page 2
Data Extracted::85242 records
page 3
Data Extracted::170484 records
page 4
Data Extracted::255726 records
page 5
Data Extracted::340968 records
page 6
Data Extracted::426210 records
page 7
Data Extracted::511452 records
page 8
Data Extracted::596694 records
.......
.......
.......
.......
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you need to update `TableResults` variable with your `getNextPage()`  variable. If you don't update it you will always be looping the same results over and over. Thats why you are getting tons of records in your output.

If you check the following samples: [Bigquery Pagination](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-pagination) and [Using Java Client Library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#complete_source_code). There are ways that we can deal with pagination results. Although not specific for single run queries.

As show on the code below, which is partially based on pagination sample, you need to use the output of `getNextPage()` to update `results` variable and proceed to perform the next iteration inside the while up until it iterates all pages but the last.

**QueryRun.Java**

```
package com.projects;

// [START bigquery_query]
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryException;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQueryOptions;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.QueryJobConfiguration; 
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.TableResult;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.Job;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobId;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.FieldValueList;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.JobInfo;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.BigQuery.QueryResultsOption;
import java.util.UUID;

import sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.Page;

public class QueryRun {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String projectId = "bigquery-public-data";
    String datasetName = "covid19_ecdc_eu";
    String tableName = "covid_19_geographic_distribution_worldwide";
    String query =
        "SELECT * "
            + " FROM `"
            + projectId
            + "."
            + datasetName
            + "."
            + tableName
            + "`"
            + " LIMIT 100";
    System.out.println(query);
    query(query);
  }

  public static void query(String query) {
    try {
      BigQuery bigquery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
      QueryJobConfiguration queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build();

      // Create a job ID so that we can safely retry.
      JobId jobId = JobId.of(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
      Job queryJob = bigquery.create(JobInfo.newBuilder(queryConfig).setJobId(jobId).build());

      TableResult results = queryJob.getQueryResults(QueryResultsOption.pageSize(10));

      int i = 0;
      int j =0; 

      // get all paged data except last line
      while(results.hasNextPage()) {
        j++;   
        for (FieldValueList row : results.getValues()) { 
            i++;
        }
        results = results.getNextPage();
        print_msg(i,j);
      }

      // last line run
      j++;
      for (FieldValueList row : results.getValues()) {  
        i++;
      }
      print_msg(i,j);

      System.out.println("Query performed successfully.");
    } catch (BigQueryException | InterruptedException e) {
      System.out.println("Query not performed \n" + e.toString());
    }
  }

  public static void print_msg(int i,int j)
  {
    System.out.println("page " + j);
    System.out.println("Data Extracted::" + i + " records"); 
  }

} 
// [END bigquery_query]
```

**output:**

```
SELECT *  FROM `bigquery-public-data.covid19_ecdc_eu.covid_19_geographic_distribution_worldwide` LIMIT 100
page 1
Data Extracted::10 records
page 2
Data Extracted::20 records
page 3
Data Extracted::30 records
page 4
Data Extracted::40 records
page 5
Data Extracted::50 records
page 6
Data Extracted::60 records
page 7
Data Extracted::70 records
page 8
Data Extracted::80 records
page 9
Data Extracted::90 records
page 10
Data Extracted::100 records
Query performed successfully.
```

As a final note, there are not official sample about pagination for queries so I'm not totally sure of the recommended way to handle pagination with java. Its not quite clear on the [BigQuery for Java](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/com/google/cloud/bigquery/BigQuery.html) documentation page. If you can update your question with your approach to pagination I would appreciate.

If you have issues running the attached sample please see [Using the BigQuery Java client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) sample, its [github](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquery/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/bigquery/Query.java) page and its `pom.xml` file inside of it and check if you are in compliance with it.

Comment: Will there be any performance improvements when using results.getValues() over pagination and results.iterateAll().

Comment: There should be as `getValues` and pagination its better than `iterateAll` which bring all records. Difference should be noted on huge results. Also, I have no check if there is a way to read  results async with this.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. Really Helps. one more question, Could you please share thoughts on Handling rateLimitExceeded Error. Not a Spring boot application. How best we can handle this issue ?

Comment: I think you will have to rise a new question specifying the details of the scenario that triggers such message as more details are needed to provide an accurate answer. As a guess, Could it be to something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36350555/what-causes-403-ratelimitexceeded)? If so, you will have to check your service limits and settings maybe you can increase or manage such limits/constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I Am late in the response.
But reading on the java client guide (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/quickstarts/quickstart-client-libraries#complete_source_code)

it says that:

> Iterate over the QueryResponse to get all the rows in the results. The iterator automatically handles pagination. Each FieldList exposes the columns by numeric index or column name.

Sai that, it should be easier to simply use the iterateAll() method.

Let me know if I Am wrong.